# Zinc and copper salt bridge replacement

Tags: redox

If I were to replace $\ce{Zn}$ with $\ce{Al}$ in  $\ce{Zn|Zn^2+ || Cu^2+|Cu}$. Would it produce the same results?

Comment: No, the results would be quite different. You might still be able to get some voltage, though.

Answer (score 3):

**No, it would not**.

$\ce{Al}$ is normally covered by oxide layer which effectively renders it ***inert*** to most things. Your cell would stop dead, as if the electrodes were made out of wood.

Then again, you might want to know whether it is possible to remove the said layer. Yes, it can be done, but then $\ce{Al}$ turns out to be just ***too active***. It reacts with water quite readily (albeit not as spectacularly as $\ce{Na}$). Merry little bubbles of $\ce{H2}$ will pop up, flakes of $\ce{Al(OH)3}$ will drop to the bottom, and in a matter of an hour or so your electrode will be gone. While it lasts, the cell will produce some voltage; as **Dr.J.** correctly noted, it will be even *greater* than that of the normal $\ce{Cu/Zn}$ cell.

So it goes.

Answer (score 0):

The reduction potential for Al is different from that for Zn, so you will definitely obtain different results.  The voltage produced with Al will be almost twice the voltage obtained with Zn.

Comment: There are more important differences than that.

Comment: @Ivan For example? I would think one of the most important factors in a galvanic cell would be the voltage that is generated.